# rss headlines display as marquee text on c#.net web form?

Tags: c#, rss, scripting, webforms, marquee

What is the best way or what is the best script that rss headlines display as marquee text on c#.net web form?

Answer (score 0):

Did you search Google at all before coming here?  I searched on "jquery create marquee" and found a lot of possibilities.

jquery and asp.net are going to have a tight relationship soon, so that is why i selected a jquery solution for my search.

Comment: thank you. i just want to know best way about that.NOW i'll search about jquery marquee